# SAPUI5 in-table search (Uncaught Error: Only "String" values are supported for the FilterOperator: "Contains".)

Tags: type-conversion, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 table with both String value data (e.g. names) and integer data (e.g. IDs). When I use the in-table search options for strings, it works perfectly.

When I try to search for part of an ID, it throws the following error:

> (Uncaught Error: Only "String" values are supported for the
>   FilterOperator: "Contains".)

I want to search through my integers as though they were strings

Attempt 1:

```
var oTextView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView( {
            text : {
                path : "id",
                formatter : function(oContext) {
                    if (oContext) {
                        return oContext.toString();
                    } else
                        return;
                }
                }
            });
```

Attempt 2:

```
var oTextView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView( {
            text : {
                path : "id",
                type : new sap.ui.model.type.String(),
                }
            });
```

Attempt 3:

combining previous attempts with this (result is I cannot open in-table search for this column at all anymore):

```
oColumn.setFilterProperty(sap.ui.model.type.String())
oColumn.setSortProperty(new sap.ui.model.type.String())
```

*Edit: view/controller*

> view:

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();
oTable.setModel(sap.ui.getCore().getModel("myModel"));
oTable.bindRows("/myPath");

var oTextView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView();
            oTextView.bindProperty("text", "myProperty");

var oColumn =   var oColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
label : new sap.ui.commons.Label( {
                text : "My Column"
            }),
            template : oTextView,
            sortProperty : "myProperty",
            filterProperty : "myProperty",
});
oTable.addColumn(oColumn);
```

> Controller:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(MyData); 
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "myModel");
```

Comment: oColumn.setFilterProperty(sap.ui.model.type.String())
oColumn.setSortProperty(new sap.ui.model.type.String())
above statements are wrong they take only string as parameters not objects. Could you put complete view and controller.

Comment: @SunilBN this is how I normally build up my tables (I stripped it down to the essentials). It works for strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and casting to string solved it. However I will file a bug report, because the filter should also work with numbers. Especially because the sorting is only working as expected with numbers. As a work around, I did the following:

1. Cast to string via: `var my_string = my_num.toString();` This seems better, then the implicit cast via the concatination proposed above.
2. Use the string value in the binding for the filter
3. Use the number value in the binding for the sorting

Here some pseudo code, because someone asked for it. The string value is only added to the model for the sorting:

```
var your_data_model = [{int_value = 111},{int_value=222}];
your_data_model[0].string_value = "111"; //add a string value for filter
your_data_model[1].string_value = "222"; //add a string value for filter

//in your table object add the sorting as usal on the column level
var oColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label : oLabel,
    template : oObject
});
oColumn.setSortProperty("int_value"); //sort well for numbers
oColumn.setFilterProperty("string_value"); //filter worlds for string
```

Comment: Could you please post the full code? I still cannot get this to work

Comment: Adjusted the initial response. I hope it is clear how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var oTextView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView( {
    text : "" + "{id}" + ""
});
```

This way your Integers will be given out as strings

Comment: I tried it but it still sees the field as an int, even with a " " instead of an empty string. I think the filter is using the model (which has an int), because the column probably cannot be an int with a space behind it)

(I used **data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax = "complex"**)

Answer (score 0):

use filterType="sap.ui.model.type.Integer" can fix this issue