# Filter Operator for Numbers

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have multiple type of columns(String and Integer) in the table. I tried to apply filters for each column. Then I figure out one point here, i.e. Filter is working for String and it is throwing the below error while trying to filter Numeric columns

> "Uncaught Error: Only "String" values are supported for the
>   FilterOperator: "Contains"."

And I don't want to change the datatype from Numeric to String. So, can you please suggest some other approach for this issue.

Note: I have checked the below link too. But I am looking for some other approach 
[SAPUI5 in-table search (Uncaught Error: Only “String” values are supported for the FilterOperator: “Contains”.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372311/sapui5-in-table-search-uncaught-error-only-string-values-are-supported-for-t)

Comment: Can you maybe add some sample data?

Comment: `Contains` works only for `Strings` you can go through other [sap.ui.model.FilterOperator](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator/properties)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you

`new sap.ui.model.Filter([
   new sap.ui.model.Filter("PropertyName", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, query)
 ])`

List of *filter operator for integer* - `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ`, `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.GE`, `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.GT`, `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.LE`, `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.LT` and `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE`

Reference: [Model Filter Operators](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator/properties) are the list of different filter operators you can use based on your requirement.